# Checking if List Of String Contains

Tags: vb.net, list

I would like to check if a string exists in a List(Of String).

The compiler tells me that "Value of String can not be converted to Predicate(Of String) in this code:

```
Private _LockedImageGUIDs As New List(Of String)

If Not _LockedImageGUIDs.Exists(uImageGUID) Then
    _LockedImageGUIDs.Add(uImageGUID)
End If
```

I would like to know how to do that correctly.

Comment: Use Contains() over Exists(). Additionally, use the Guid data type if you're storing Guids.

Comment: If you're going to have a lot of members in this list, I would suggest using a HashSet(of String) instead of List(of String). HashSet has a somewhat larger memory footprint, but access time is much better, at least for large collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation.

As the error is trying to tell you, `Exists()` doesn't take an item.

You want the aptly-named `Contains()` function.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot simpler to use Contains, but if you want to use Exists then you should write something like this

```
if Not _LockedImageGUIDs.Exists(Function(x) uImageGUID = x) Then
    ....
```

As you can see the Contains approach is simpler and faster, while I think Exists should be used when your comparison logic is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private _LockedImageGUIDs As New List(Of String)

If Not _LockedImageGUIDs.contains(uImageGUID) Then
_LockedImageGUIDs.Add(uImageGUID)
End If
```